# How can I stop a process that is started from a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am facing difficulty to stop a process that I have started from a service in another user session, basically the service will start a process once a user login/ unlock/ connect, this step works perfectly, after that I save the process information(id, etc) in order to be able later to close it via `Process.CloseMainWindow()`.

My issue here is the process that I have started never get closed using the mentioned method, also, after checking the process id existence during the time of closing it is present, but when I checked for the process name it returns `Idle`.

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription sessionChangeDescription)
{
    try 
    {
        if (sessionChangeDescription.SessionId > 0) 
        { 
            var userInfo = TermServicesManager.GetSessionInfo(Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName, sessionChangeDescription.SessionId);
            IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(userInfo.ClientAddress.Address.Skip(2).Take(4).ToArray());

            if (!rdpSessionList.ContainsKey(sessionChangeDescription.SessionId))
            {
                onRdpSession.sessionId = sessionChangeDescription.SessionId;
                onRdpSession.ipAddress = ipAddress.ToString();
                onRdpSession.userName = userInfo.UserName;
                onRdpSession.sessionDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH'-'mm'-'ss");
                onRdpSession.recordFileName = onRdpSession.generateRecordFileName();
            }
            else
            {
                onRdpSession = rdpSessionList[sessionChangeDescription.SessionId];
            }

            switch (sessionChangeDescription.Reason)
            {
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                case SessionChangeReason.RemoteConnect:
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:
                    int processId = -1;
                    string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\SessionFormRecorder.exe";
                    filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                    RunInUserSession.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(onRdpSession.sessionId, "c:\\SessionFormRecorder.exe", null, null, false, processId);
                    onRdpSession.processId = processId;
                    WriteToFile("SessionChange" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ", SessionUnlock|RemoteConnect|SessionLogon [" + sessionChangeDescription.SessionId.ToString() + "]" + ", User: " + userInfo.UserName + ", Connect state: " + userInfo.ConnectState.ToString() + ", Client address: " + ipAddress.ToString() + ", user: " + userInfo.UserName + ", WinStationName: " + userInfo.WinStationName.ToString());
                            
                    break;

                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
                case SessionChangeReason.RemoteDisconnect:
                    Process process = null;
                    process = Process.GetProcessById(onRdpSession.processId);
                    process.CloseMainWindow();
                    WriteToFile("SessionChange: " + onRdpSession.ToString() + ", Process name: " + process.ProcessName + ", " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " RemoteDisconnect|SessionLogoff|SessionLock [" + sessionChangeDescription.SessionId.ToString() + "]" + ", User: " + userInfo.UserName + ", Connect state: " + userInfo.ConnectState.ToString() + ", Client address: " + ipAddress.ToString() + ", user: " + userInfo.UserName + ", WinStationName: " + userInfo.WinStationName.ToString());
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WriteToFile("SessionChange exception: " + ex.Message + " || " + sessionChangeDescription.SessionId.ToString() + " || " + onRdpSession.sessionId.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What account is used to start service?  Same account (or admin) is needed to close service.  VS doesn't start automatically in Admin mode.  You need to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Services interacting with the desktop is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: If you capture the result of CloseMainWindow is it true? i.e. what does `bool result = process.CloseMainWindow();` give you? I think you might want to call `Close` after calling CloseMainWindow. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng I used an admin account to start the service.

Comment: The you need to stop the service with an Admin.  So c# code must be run as an Admin

Comment: @jdweng Would you explain more please?

Comment: You need to get process by name (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=net-6.0) and then kill https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50ecbcf2-d2d3-4f21-9775-5b8be1bd4346/how-to-terminate-a-process-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral&force_isolation=true